# What could cause an 101 Error in WAMP under Windows 7?

Tags: apache-2.2, windows-7

I'be been using WAMP for local development for quite a while now but lately I've been getting an Error 101 message when I browse localhost sites. It's possible for this to have appeared after the last WAMP update but I'm not 100% sure on this. If I try again and again, after several page refreshes it works but it's really annoying!

The exact error message is:

```
Error 101 (net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET): Unknown error.
```

This is my configuration:

- OS:     Windows 7
- Apache: 2.2.11
- PHP:    5.2.9-2
- WAMP:   2.0

Also the local scripts connect to a remote MySQL server, they don't use the local MySQL(I don't know if it matters, just though I let you know).

I've been looking into the apache logs and I've found the following. It seems that the apache server keeps restarting and I can't figure why:

```
[Wed Oct 14 13:52:30 2009] [notice] Parent: child process exited with status 255 -- Restarting.
[Wed Oct 14 13:52:30 2009] [notice] Apache/2.2.11 (Win32) PHP/5.2.9-2 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Wed Oct 14 13:52:30 2009] [notice] Server built: Dec 10 2008 00:10:06
[Wed Oct 14 13:52:30 2009] [notice] Parent: Created child process 6784
[Wed Oct 14 13:52:31 2009] [notice] Child 6784: Child process is running
[Wed Oct 14 13:52:31 2009] [notice] Child 6784: Acquired the start mutex.
[Wed Oct 14 13:52:31 2009] [notice] Child 6784: Starting 64 worker threads.
[Wed Oct 14 13:52:31 2009] [notice] Child 6784: Starting thread to listen on port 80.
[Wed Oct 14 13:52:32 2009] [notice] Parent: child process exited with status 255 -- Restarting.
[Wed Oct 14 13:52:33 2009] [notice] Apache/2.2.11 (Win32) PHP/5.2.9-2 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Wed Oct 14 13:52:33 2009] [notice] Server built: Dec 10 2008 00:10:06
[Wed Oct 14 13:52:33 2009] [notice] Parent: Created child process 3572
[Wed Oct 14 13:52:33 2009] [notice] Child 3572: Child process is running
[Wed Oct 14 13:52:33 2009] [notice] Child 3572: Acquired the start mutex.
[Wed Oct 14 13:52:33 2009] [notice] Child 3572: Starting 64 worker threads.
[Wed Oct 14 13:52:33 2009] [notice] Child 3572: Starting thread to listen on port 80.
```

Also I've checked Windows Firewall and disabled any other protection that I have on this computer with no improvement.

Thanks!

Comment: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=48347 - the problem may be in this bug

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem.

- OS: Windows 7
- Server: Apache 2.2.17-win32
- MySQL: 5.1.53-win32
- PHP: 5.2.14-Win32

Replacing `C:/<MySQL Dir>/bin/libMySQL.dll` with `C:/PHP/libmysql.dll` solved my problem.

The error occurs when you try to connect to database with mysql_connect. It is shown on the following line in error log above.

```
[Wed Oct 14 13:52:32 2009] [notice] Parent: child process exited with status 255 -- Restarting.
```

So Apache crashes when mysql_connect tries to connect. So use proper `libmysql.dll` is helpful here.

Comment: hi where to replace the file which you are taking about?

Answer (score 1):

I ran across something very much like this --- but my configuration included Drupal in addition to PHP. So for you Drupal people out there, I would suggest checking for a function recursively calling itself.

In my case, I was trying to move a Drupal installation from one machine to another. The old system had Log4Drupal enabled and configured to write to a log file on a drive and folder that did not exist on the new machine. Near as I could tell, the log function tried to report something and when that failed, it tried to log the failure, etc.

To work around the problem, it was useful to look in the database and find out what file Log4Drupal was using. The MySQL query is "select * from variable where name like 'log%'". I created all the folders needed to make that path good. Then my Drupal system was able to start and I could use Log4Drupal's admin page.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.

You should close the connection at the end of your page code using the connection resource. This worked for me:

```
mysql_close($conn);
```

where `$conn` is your MySQL database connection resource variable which you have used to connect to MySQL database.

Answer (score 1):

Got the same problem with **WampServer 2.1** + Chrome 15.0 + Eclipse PDT (SDK 2.1.1, runtime 2.1.3), on Windows 7.

I resolved it by:

- Installing latest version of **WampServer (2.2D 32bits)**
- Closed Eclipse, Chrome, stopped WampServer, then reopened / restarted all the stuff

Seems it was due to an **XDebug bug** (fixed): http://bugs.xdebug.org/view.php?id=410

Answer (score 0):

The connection reset must be done by the win7 firewall, you have to open the Windows Firewall (just type it to the open start menu it will appear) and explicitly allow port 80. I hope it helps.

Comment: I've checked Windows Firewall and Apache is allowed on port 80. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I ran across the problem and don't have an answer to what caused the error,

for me worked to disable de mysqli extension. Wamp worked again as usual (slow with xdebug), but phpmyadmin lost a lot of functionalities.