# import large CSV using phpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, php

I have a very large CSV file (24 MB) that I am trying to import using the import CSV from phpMyAdmin, however it always breaks down in the middle of import. What should I do to solve this?

The error I get is:

```
Error 101 (net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET): Unknown error
```

Comment: Based on the answers in a different thread, this error might be related to the php driver for MySQL. http://serverfault.com/questions/74313

Comment: If you're using XAMPP, check your error.log file (xampp\apache\logs\error.log) to see if there's any clues on the error you're getting.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is probably caused by the timeout or the maximum filesize for PHP scripts on your server.

Try setting [max_execution_time](http://php.net/manual/info.configuration.php#ini.max-execution-time) and [max_input_time](http://php.net/manual/info.configuration.php#ini.max-input-time) to a higher value. The configuration file options for maximum file sizes have already been mentioned by kenny.r.

Answer (score 2):

You can increase the values for `upload_max_filesize` and `post_max_size` in your `php.ini` file.

This will allow you to upload the entire file, so that MySQL can properly process it.

Comment: +1, probably just choking on the large file size.

Comment: I actually tried setting the size to a large value and it still didn't work

Comment: Your upload speed might be too slow for your timeout value. Try joschi's suggestion.

Comment: I did change the max_execution_time to 4 minutes and even before 4 min it crashes